# Textmate newbie question: how to indent CSS

Tags: css, textmate, indentation

New to TextMate and can't find the answer in the documentation.

I've saved an empty file as CSS and the 'active bundle' is showing as CSS, at the bottom of the screen.

I've then pasted in a bunch of CSS from elsewhere (a minified page). However, it's all pasted in as a single line.

How can I indent it to look like 'proper' CSS, using TextMate? Text + Indent just indents the whole line by a single tab.

thanks!

Comment: If the CSS is minified it is normal that is in single line. You should use CSS tidy or something to format it, not sure if textmate can format CSS. Try this link http://www.cleancss.com/

Comment: Some promising-looking links for TextMate in the comments here: http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/page/single-line-vs-multi-line-css-a-tool-to-end-the-debate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Bundles > CSS > Format CSS` or `^Q` should do the trick.